# Polygon inside polygon in libgdx and box2d

Tags: java, box2d, polygon, libgdx, bounds

I'm new in libgdx and box2d and I would like to know if there's an easy way to put a polygon randomly inside the bounds of another polygon.

**EDIT**

I want something like this:

[image: What I want]

Where the black polygon could be positioned in any other zone inside the green polygon and never outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility of easy placing one polygon inside another in Box2D. Solution is shown on the drawing below:

[image]

Yellow rectangles is the first body, green - second. Each yellow rectangle is separate fixture.

Comment: In my case, I want the green polygon to be inside another polygon and not surrounded by polygons. So, do I need to make the math to know the min and max values for X, randomize X and then do the same for Y?

Comment: Is you question is how to calculate coordinates of black polygon? There is no way that black polygon can physically interact with green in Box2D.

Comment: So, in other words, there's no way to generate the black polygon inside the bounds of the green polygon using the edges or something like that right? Just one more question... Does Box2D let me get the new vertices of a rotated polygon?

Comment: To rotate multiply every vertex to b2Rot structure with b2Mul function.